# QT, C++: How do Signal and Slots works with listWidgetItems?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slots

I have a `WidgetList` with checkboxes and I want to use these as a signal to call the `slotTest` function.

Unfortunately, the code does not work and I can not find a solution:

```
connect(ui->listWidget, SIGNAL(item->checkState()), this, SLOT(slotTest()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

here more code:

```
 QStringList list;
    list << "CH1 100kHz" << "CH2 100kHz" << "CH3 100kHz";
    model->setStringList(list);
    ui->listView->setModel(model);
    ui->listView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::AnyKeyPressed | QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked);
    //ui->listView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::S)
    ui->listWidget->addItems(list);



    QListWidgetItem* item = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ui->listWidget->count(); ++i){
        item = ui->listWidget->item(i);
        item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
        item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);

        item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
        //connect(ui->listWidget, SIGNAL(itemClicked()), this, SLOT(slotTest()), Qt::QueuedConnection);

        // bool ischeck=ui->listWidget->item(i)->checkState();
        connect(ui->listWidget, SIGNAL(item->checkState()), this, SLOT(slotTest()), Qt::QueuedConnection);

    }
```

Comment: Please add a complete [MCVE]. Because on a first glance, that line alone seems ok (except for the `Qt::QueuedConnection` with which I am at least not familiar.

Comment: You use signal/slot mechanism wrongly. I think you must reread https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html once more.

Comment: @vahancho i cant see why this dosnt work

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all, [`checkState()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#checkState) is not a signal, so you can't connect to it.
Furthermore, the first parameter of the [`connect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) call should be the actual sender of the signal, not its parent.

One alternative would be to connect to one of the signals emitted by the [`QListWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemActivated) when the user interacts with the controls. You should test them out in order to determine which one fits your use case best.

For example:

```
QObject::connect(ui->listWidget, &QListWidget::itemChanged, this, &MainWindow::slotTest);
void MainWindow::slotTest(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    qInfo() << item->checkState();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I only have the problem that always all signals are output either as checked or unchecked. So if I have 100 signals the output at the consol will be 100 times checked or unchecked (all the same all checked or unchecked) depending on what I chose last

Comment: That happens because your connect call is inside the for loop. Just move it outside of it, since you only have to do it once.